# Symbolic Summation in Matlab using symsum

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In matlab, I implemented the sum of series (x^k) / (2*k) when k is from 1 to 6, as following:

```
syms x;
syms k real;
symsum(x^k/(2*k), k, 1, 6)
```

The above sum has only one symbolic variable (x). Now I want to implement the following sum in Matlab (alpha and n are constant). As you can see, depending on the value of n, we will have different number of symbolic variables. For example, if n=2 then we have 2 symbolic variables x1 and x2. If n=4 then we have 4 symbolic variables x1,x2,x3 and x4. How can I implement this in Matlab?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a 1xN vector of symbolic variables, by using

```
A=sym('A',[1 N]);
```

and then the `i`-th element is accessed using `A(i)`.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html#brvhmob-1) for more detail.

As for writing the sum, I can't really help. I think you may to use a for loop and specify the indices, i.e.

```
S=0;
for i=1:N/2
    S=S+alpha*(x(2*i)-x(2*i-1)^2)+(1-x(2*i-1))^2;
end
```

but that doesn't simplify the answer at all. I'm not aware of a better method though.

Comment: I think, it should be A(i) not Ai.
Do you have any hint on how to write the sigma?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have updated my answer, but I can't help with the sum really, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If Mupad solution is admissible for you, try

```
sum(alpha*(x(2*k)-x(2*k-1)^2)+(1-x(2*k-1))^2, k=1..n/2)
```

of course you should state `alpha` and `n`